# A problem with a colourful longtable - I can see a half text in a double row only

Tags: color, longtable

Why do I see only one half of text? See the picture below.  I use the environment `longtable` and I try to colour my whole table in one colour.

Thanks for help.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a6paper]{article}
%46paper
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=slovak,english]{babel}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[a6paper, top=15mm, left=10mm, right=10mm, bottom=10mm,foot=5mm,marginparsep=0mm]{geometry}
%showframe
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\pagenumbering{alph}
%\pagenumbering{Roman}

\usepackage{ marvosym }
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{tfrupee}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{marvosym}
%----------------------------------------------
\usepackage{booktabs,longtable,makecell} 
%------------------------------------------------ 
\usepackage{ wasysym}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ amssymb }
\usepackage{amsmath}
%---------------------------------------
%\usepackage{tgbonum} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
%------------------------------------------
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ marvosym }
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{ wasysym }
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}   
%---
\makeglossaries
%\input{adj_1.txt}
\input{adj_2.txt}


\begin{document}
\catcode`\-=12
\sloppy

\clearpage
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} 
%\setcounter{page}{1} 
%\tableofcontents
%\thispagestyle{empty}



{\Large
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\cellcolor{Goldenrod} txt & \cellcolor{Goldenrod} \multirow{2}{*}{txt} & \cellcolor{Goldenrod} \multirow{16}{*}{txt} \\
\cellcolor{Goldenrod} txt & \cellcolor{Goldenrod}                      & \cellcolor{Goldenrod} \\ \cline{1-2} 
\cellcolor{Goldenrod} txt & \cellcolor{Goldenrod} \multirow{2}{*}{txt} & \cellcolor{Goldenrod} \\ \cline{1-1}
\cellcolor{Goldenrod} txt & \cellcolor{Goldenrod}                      & \cellcolor{Goldenrod} \\ \cline{1-2} 
\cellcolor{Goldenrod} txt & \cellcolor{Goldenrod} \multirow{2}{*}{txt} & \cellcolor{Goldenrod} \\ \cline{1-1}
\cellcolor{Goldenrod} txt & \cellcolor{Goldenrod}                      & \cellcolor{Goldenrod} \\ \cline{1-2} 
\cellcolor{Goldenrod} txt & \cellcolor{Goldenrod} \multirow{2}{*}{txt} & \cellcolor{Goldenrod} \\ \cline{1-1}
\cellcolor{Goldenrod} txt & \cellcolor{Goldenrod}                      & \cellcolor{Goldenrod} \\ \cline{1-2} 
\cellcolor{Goldenrod} txt & \cellcolor{Goldenrod} \multirow{2}{*}{txt} & \cellcolor{Goldenrod} \\ \cline{1-1}
\cellcolor{Goldenrod} txt & \cellcolor{Goldenrod}                      & \cellcolor{Goldenrod} \\ \cline{1-2} 
\cellcolor{Goldenrod} txt & \cellcolor{Goldenrod} \multirow{2}{*}{txt} & \cellcolor{Goldenrod} \\ \cline{1-1}
\cellcolor{Goldenrod} txt & \cellcolor{Goldenrod}                      & \cellcolor{Goldenrod} \\ \cline{1-2} 
\cellcolor{Goldenrod} txt & \cellcolor{Goldenrod} \multirow{2}{*}{txt} & \cellcolor{Goldenrod} \\ \cline{1-1}
\cellcolor{Goldenrod} txt & \cellcolor{Goldenrod}                      & \cellcolor{Goldenrod} \\ \cline{1-2} 
\cellcolor{Goldenrod} txt & \cellcolor{Goldenrod} \multirow{2}{*}{txt} & \cellcolor{Goldenrod} \\ \cline{1-1}
\cellcolor{Goldenrod} txt & \cellcolor{Goldenrod}                      & \cellcolor{Goldenrod} \\ \cline{1-1}
\hline
\end{longtable}
}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you load nearly all packages multiple times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put  `\multirow` in the *last* row, with a negative number of rows.  There remains a problem: the `\cline` will not appear  with their full thickness. A (not perfect) solution consists in using `hhline` instead, with a black colour first, then with the background colour. Also, you don't have to write `cellcolor` in each cell: the `\rowcolors` from `xcolor` will set every row withe background colour.

*Edit:* I've solved the problem of discontinuous vertical lines, thanks to @David Carlisle.  As the coding is rather long, I defined shortcuts for the two types of horizontal rules used here: `\hhlinebgg` and `\hhlinebbg`:

```
    \documentclass[10pt,a6paper]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[main=slovak,english]{babel}
    \usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
    \usepackage[a6paper, top=15mm, hmargin=10mm, bottom=10mm,foot=5mm,marginparsep=0mm]{geometry}
    %showframe
    \usepackage{tipa}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{lscape}
    \usepackage{pdflscape}

    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{longtable, tabularx, makecell, multirow, booktabs, hhline}
    \usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    %\pagenumbering{alph}
    %\pagenumbering{Roman}

    \usepackage{ wasysym, marvosym }
    \usepackage{fontawesome}
    \usepackage{stackengine}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    %------------------------------------------------
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{ amssymb }
    %---------------------------------------
    \usepackage{listings}
    \usepackage{framed}
    \usepackage{soul}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \def\blackrule{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}}
    \def\goldrule{\expandafter>{\arrayrulecolor{Goldenrod}}}
    \newcommand*{\hhlinebgg}{\hhline{->{\arrayrulecolor{Goldenrod}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{Goldenrod}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|}
}
   \newcommand*{\hhlinebbg}{\hhline{-->{\arrayrulecolor{Goldenrod}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|}}

    \begin{document}
    \catcode`\-=12
    \sloppy
    \clearpage

    {\Large
    \rowcolors{1}{Goldenrod}{Goldenrod}
    \begin{longtable}{|*{3}{l|}}%
    \hhline{---}
    txt  & &  \\
    \hhlinebgg%
     txt & \multirow{-2}{*}{txt} & \\
     \hhlinebbg
      txt & & \\
      \hhlinebgg
      txt & \multirow{-2}{*}{txt} & \\
     \hhlinebbg
     txt & & \\
      \hhlinebgg
     txt & \multirow{-2}{*}{txt} & \\
     \hhlinebbg
     txt & & \\
      \hhlinebgg
     txt & \multirow{-2}{*}{txt} &\\
     \hhlinebbg
     txt & & \\
     \hhlinebgg
     txt & \multirow{-2}{*}{txt} & \\
     \hhlinebbg
     txt & & \\
     \hhlinebgg
     txt & \multirow{-2}{*}{txt} & \\
     \hhlinebbg
     txt & & \\
     \hhlinebgg
     txt & \multirow{-2}{*}{txt} & \\
     \hhlinebbg
     txt & & \\
     \hhlinebgg
     txt & \multirow{-2}{*}{txt} & \multirow{-16}{*}{txt}\\
     \hhline{---}
    \end{longtable}
    }

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But colour of lines inside the table is white. It is not black.

Comment: With this code? The only problem I have, which you can notice on the image above is pale yellow second part of the `\hhline`s (the part that should be Goldenrod), due to a default of the viewer (disappears on zooming) and the discontinuities of the 3rd and 4th vertical lines, which I couldn't remove (in theory, there should be no discontinuity).

Comment: @Bernard I do not see the horizontal lines with xpdf, the gaps in the vertical lines are because you have to go back to black so the brilliantly simple user interface of : `\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}->{\arrayrulecolor{Goldenrod}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{Goldenrod}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|}`

Comment: @David Carlisle: Thanks a lot! I worship at your feet! I  found it useful to define shortcuts , since these commands are repetitive – and verbose, albeit brilliantly simple…

Answer (score 2):

Move the multirow line in the second line, see the documentation of multirow. And clean up your preamble, you are loading a lot of packages twice.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a6paper]{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{multirow}



\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\cellcolor{Goldenrod} txt & \cellcolor{Goldenrod}  & \cellcolor{Goldenrod} \multirow{16}{*}{txt} \\
\cellcolor{Goldenrod} txt & \cellcolor{Goldenrod}  \multirow{-2}{*}{txt}                    & \cellcolor{Goldenrod} \\ \cline{1-2}

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer looks very interesting. I did not know `\multirow` can be negative.

Comment: But when I change width of lines I get white gaps. Can you tell me how I can fix it?