# The colourful longtable and change of width of lines.

Tags: longtable, width, colortbl

I have got one colourful longtable. I want to change width of lines in some rows. I mean `\cline`. I have found out the information but when I did it I got white gaps in my table. See the picture below. How can I fix my problem?

Thanks for help.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a6paper]{article}
%46paper
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=slovak,english]{babel}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[a6paper, top=15mm, hmargin=10mm, bottom=10mm,foot=5mm,marginparsep=0mm]{geometry}
%showframe
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable, tabularx, makecell, multirow, booktabs, hhline}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\pagenumbering{alph}
%\pagenumbering{Roman}

\usepackage{ wasysym, marvosym }
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{textcomp}
%------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ amssymb }
%---------------------------------------
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%---------------------------------------
% different width of a line
\makeatletter
\def\Cline#1#2{\@Cline#1#2\@nil}
\def\@Cline#1-#2#3\@nil{%
  \omit
  \@multicnt#1%
  \advance\@multispan\m@ne
  \ifnum\@multicnt=\@ne\@firstofone{&\omit}\fi
  \@multicnt#2%
  \advance\@multicnt-#1%
  \advance\@multispan\@ne
  \leaders\hrule\@height#3\hfill
  \cr}
\makeatother
%-------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\catcode`\-=12
\sloppy

\clearpage

{\Large
\begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
\hline
\cellcolor{BurntOrange}  ABC & \cellcolor{BurntOrange}                        & \cellcolor{BurntOrange} \\  \Cline{1-1}{1pt}
\cellcolor{BurntOrange}  ABC & \cellcolor{BurntOrange} \multirow{-2}{*}{ABC}  & \cellcolor{BurntOrange} \\  \Cline{1-2}{1pt}
\cellcolor{BurntOrange}  ABC & \cellcolor{BurntOrange}                        & \cellcolor{BurntOrange} \\  \Cline{1-1}{1pt}
\cellcolor{BurntOrange}  ABC & \cellcolor{BurntOrange} \multirow{-2}{*}{ABC}  & \cellcolor{BurntOrange} \multirow{-4}{*}{ABC} \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the colortbl documentation explicitly states that cline should not be used (and taht you can use hhline instead)

Comment: @David Carlisle: I gad provided such a code for a [previous post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370631/a-problem-wtih-a-colourful-longtable-i-can-see-a-half-text-in-a-double-row-onl/370661#370661) from the O.P. However, the vertical lines had discontinuities although the code was, roughly, `\hhline{|-|-|-|}` + colour specifications. Could you take a look and tell me what I missed?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have read the documentation but I have still got the same problem - the while gaps.

Comment: @Bernard I added a comment there. this question appears to be an exact duplicate of the previous?

Comment: @David Carlisle: It's closely linked, but it's focused on the white lines, due to the use of a new `\Cline` command, probably because of the discontinous vertical lines in the initial version of my answer (thanks again!) with `\hhline`.

Comment: @ĽubomírMasarovič: Please take a look at the new version of my answer to you previous post. The remaining problems have been solved.